# Table: Stretch content and put header and footer to the edges

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I have component which with a `table`. The table looks like

```
<div>    
  <table>
    <thead>...
    <tbody>...
    <tfoot>...
  </table>
</div>
```

For my whole layout I need to display approx 3 rows (in the `tbody`). All the rest of the table should go in between. Currently it looks like:

[image]

I want now to have the `thead` fixed at the top and the `tfoot` at the bottom.  My current settings look like:

```
table {
  height: calc(100% - 8px);
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
div{ max-height: 260px;}
```

I know I can fix the table with some kind of wrapping into a `div`, and set `max-height` and `overflow`. But how to layout that the `table`?

Additional request: How to fill the table to cover the whole width? Currently it doesn't stretch? (see screenshot) Setting